# How do I change startRow for maatwebsite's laravel excel package 2.0.8 for Laravel 5.2 somewhere besides the excel.php config file?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to import an excel file using maatwebsite's laravel excel package 2.0.8 for Laravel 5.2. I would like to be able to change the startRow inside my controller instead of inside the config so it doesn't affect everyone.

```
public function import()
{
    $results = Excel::load('doctors.csv', function($reader) {
    })->get();

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this before reading the file:

```
config(['excel.import.startRow' = rowNumber]);
```

It worked for me.

Source:
https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/886

Answer (score 2):

Config::set('excel.import.startRow', $rowNumber);

**$rowNumber** is a number of rows that you want to start import data from your file. Make sure you put this function before you read your file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `skip()` or `limit()` method:

```
$results = Excel::load('doctors.csv', function($reader) {})
                ->skip(1) // Skip one row
                ->get();

// Or, with limit:

$results = Excel::load('doctors.csv', function($reader) {})
                ->limit(false, 1) // Skip one row
                ->get();
```

Comment: I just tried both of these methods and unfortunately the first row only has two columns filled out and the content is more like 8 columns. The results are on the correct row but it does not give me all of the columns.