# Laravel excell skip rows when reading data using maatwebsite/excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using `maatwebsite/excel` to read data and I would like to skip the first two rows.

Reading data:

```
$data = Excel::load('storage/app/temporary'.'/'.$request->input('file'))->get();
return $data;
```

The above code returns all the rows

How do I skip the first two rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could use `limit()`

```
$data = Excel::load('storage/app/temporary'.'/'.$request->input('file'))-->limit(false, 2)->get();
return $data;
```

Or try adding this line before read-

```
config(['excel.import.startRow' = 2]);
```

this was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274521/how-do-i-change-startrow-for-maatwebsites-laravel-excel-package-2-0-8-for-larav), you can see this link to have a better understanding.

Comment: I have multiple spreadsheets with same structure and data in one file and i would like to skip for each spreadsheet

Comment: did you try with limit or skip or changing config before read??

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI glad it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `skipRows()` function:

```
$data = Excel::load('storage/app/temporary'.'/'.$request->input('file'))->skipRows(2)->get();
return $data;
```

Or you can try with:

```
$file = 'storage/app/temporary'.'/'.$request->input('file');

$data = Excel::load($file, function($reader) {
    $results = $reader->skipRows(2)->get();
    return $results;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-slice

So for example,

```
return collect($data)->slice(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code before load the Excel file. it works for me.**

```
config(['excel.import.startRow' => your_number_of_row_to_skip]);
```

**Ex:**

```
$path = $request->file('uploaded_file')->getRealPath();
config(['excel.import.startRow' => 4]);
$data = Excel::load($path)->get();
```